# Webpack and Jest in a project using imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, jestjs

I'm working on a Node project and using imports and exports all over the place.

I'm using Webpack to package the frontend code. So far as I can tell, it has to run as common JS.

I'm also using Jest, which forced me to set `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.

These two don't mix well: Webpack can't run as a module and Jest refuses to process my code as common JS. What can I do to reconcile this?

I tried other ways to run Jest with modules like modifying the test script:

```
"node --experimental-vm-modules --experimental-default-type=module node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
```

and naming the test files as `*.mjs`, but continued getting `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

`webpack.config.js` is written with `require` and relies on `__dirname`, unavailable in modules. I tried rewriting it with module syntax, but it complains about either not having a default export or not having exported a `config` object.

Comment: You have to run the tests from `package.json` and it works only with type `module`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTF-error messages. Solved by renaming `webpack.config.js` to `webpack.config.cjs`.

> [webpack-cli] ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
> This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '[...redacted...]/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.